# Script Localization on WordPress without Giving Error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I'm successfully using script localisation to pass the WordPress plugin folder to Javascript for when I'm using Ajax functions.

However, I'm getting the following error on all of my pages:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

Here is the code I'm using to do it:

```
/***** LOCALIZATION FOR PHP TO JS ***********/

wp_register_script( 'my-script', 'myscript_url' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'my-script' );
$translation_array = array( 'templateUrl' => plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) );
//after wp_enqueue_script
wp_localize_script( 'my-script', 'object_name', $translation_array );
```

It's worth noting that I never intended to call script_url. All of my javascript code is within this one plugin file.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: make sure the links that are outputted using the enqueue_script functions exist. On the page where the scripts are supposed to show, view source and make sure the paths to the scripts exist and are correct

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've enqueued your scripts properly. Something like

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my-script');

if ( ! function_exists( 'my-script' ) ){
    function my-script() {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'my-script_custom', {path to your script}, array({dependancies}),'', true );
        $translation_array = array( 'templateUrl' => plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) );
        //after wp_enqueue_script
        wp_localize_script( 'my-script_custom', 'object_name', $translation_array );

    }
}
```

should work.